Почему во flet при добавлении page.open вся страница удаляется
Пишу программу на flet. Добавил BottomSheet, который вылезает через page.open при определенных условиях при каждом обновлении страницы. Когда я его добавил, страница очистилась и ничего не было. Когда убрал page.clean, все заработало, но при смене страницы прошлая не удалилась и они наложились друг на друга. Почему я не могу использовать две эти функции вместе?
Код: (сокращеный)
import flet as ft
#другие импорты

#база данных и т.д. и т.п.

def main(page: ft.Page):
    #тут стоит настройка страницы (ширина\длина\цвет)
    
    #тут стоят функции разные
    
    def check_stake(): 
        stake_data = db.get_stake()
        return funcs.convert_iso(stake_data[1]) <= funcs.convert_iso(funcs.get_time())
    
    def route_change(e):
        page.clean() #вот тут чищу страницу
        def go_stake(e):
            page.go('/stake')
        
        if check_stake():
            stake_data = db.get_stake()
            page.open(views.stake_sheet(funcs.count_stake(stake_data[0]), stake_data[1], go_stake)) #тут открывают sheet и все ломается
        
        if page.route == '/':
            #тут всякие функции и page.add, короче views
        #...
        #много кода страниц
        #...

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.go(page.route)
    page.update()

ft.app(main)

Код BottomSheet (views.stake_sheet)
def stake_sheet(stake_before, stake_after, go_stake):
    return ft.BottomSheet(
        ft.Column(
            [
                ft.Text(f'Вы успешно застейкали -1 монет и получили -2 монет!'),
                ft.ElevatedButton(
                    'Собрать монеты',
                    bgcolor='#0089d4',
                    color='white',
                    on_click=go_stake,
                    style=ft.ButtonStyle(
                        shape=ft.RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=10)
                    )
                )
            ]
        )
    )

page.clean + page.open

page.open (вроде все норм, но все виджеты страниц уходят под область видимости и видно только первую страницу

page.clean (BottomSheet тупо нету ._.)

даже не спрашивайте, зачем мне кошелек

Решили? Я не вижу чтоб вы открывали BottomSheet после очистки страницы.

Да, я перенес открытие BottomSheet внутрь условия page.route == '/', и это работает. Но теперь почему то после закрытия BottomSheet через кнопку остается затемнения, хотя BottomSheet не видно

Рада, что Вам помог мой ответ. Будет лучше если Вы создадите новый вопрос, завтра я постараюсь найти время и посмотрю.

Не надо чтоб BottomSheet вылезал через page.open().
Когда page.clean()  внутри функции  route_change()  вы очищаете страницу,
включая BottomSheet, который вы добавляете с помощью  page.open().
Поэтому BottomSheet не отображается после очистки страницы.
Надо открываете его при необходимости внутри функции  route_change().
